# white-space not working on Firefox

Tags: html, css

I want the `<select>` `<option>`s to wrap if the text is too long.

```css
select {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<select style="width:130px;">
  <option value="47" selected="selected">Traditur Preascep irruit. Sed now possum Non adamare te. Maneam</option>
</select>
```

But when I test on Firefox, the text is hidden, not wrapped. How to fix this?

Comment: Try this https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/prevent-long-urls-from-breaking-out-of-container/

Answer (score -1):

try it...

```
<!--html-->
<select>
  <option value="47" selected="selected">Traditur Preascep irruit. Sed now possum Non adamare te. Maneam</option>
</select>

/*css*/

select {
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    width:auto;

}
```

Comment: This does nothing in Firefox.